# PHP - parsing JSON data / HTTP request

Tags: php, json

I have this php file which contains JSON data

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

echo'{"ID":"9999","RSSI":-48,"Time":"","sensors":[
{"Type":"AirFlow","Unit":"Analog","Val":0},
{"Type":"Temperature","Unit":"C","Val":28.65},
{"Type":"SkinConduct","Unit":"microSiemens","Val":-1.00},
{"Type":"SkinResist","Unit":"Ohm","Val":-1.00},
{"Type":"SkinConductVolt","Unit":"V","Val":0.49},
{"Type":"HeartRate","Unit":"BPM","Val":0},
{"Type":"02 Saturation","Unit":"%","Val":0},
{"Type":"BodyPosition","Unit":"^<>_|","Value":3}]}
{"Type":"ElectroCardioGram","Unit":"Analog","Val":3.78},
';

?>
```

and I want it to be read by another php file, requesting its data, decoding the JSON and storing the values HeartRate and ElectroCardioGram (the Val) in two variables. I cannot find any lead - where should I begin my research from?

I managed to get the data with this code
`

```
$myfile = fopen("sensorjson.php", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("sensorjson.php"));
fclose($myfile);
```

I guess I can parse the json between fopen and fclose to show more understandable results?

Comment: are the 2 files on the same server?

Comment: instead o echo, cant you assign the date to a variable, and include it?

Comment: @Dagon how can I do it?

Comment: how is the file populated?

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) will probably be useful

Comment: @Huey it is, I'm trying to implement it but I think that the JSON data have a bad format - can you check them if you are knowledgable?

Comment: @gamwtoshiston your json is not valid ... go to jsonlint.com, copy past it, it will show you where there is an issue.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg thank you, the json was indeed wrong, now I corrected it. with var_dump i get something like this array(4) { ["ID"]=> string(4) "9999" ["RSSI"]=> int(-48) ["Time"]=> string(0) "" ["sensors"]=> array(9) { [0]=> array(3) { ["Type"]=> string(7) "AirFlow" ["Unit"]=> string(6)  , how can I get clean data?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) for getting the file from a server (or the same server) and putting it into a string, and then you can use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to manipulate the data.

Comment: I found 2 ways of getting the file already, I'm confused with json_decode. how can I use it exactly to manipulate the data?

Comment: Following your post, you're going to want to use a URL like http://localhost/json.php so php parses the file you wrote and then echo's just the json. And the json isn't quite valid, the last bit maybe a little off, heres an example with it modified; [link](http://codepad.org/ODvRjqLB)